# I'm having trouble testing with null-safety

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

I'm trying to run a test in dart and I'm getting the following return:

> type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Future<Either<FailureLogin, LoginUser>>'

**login_with_user_test.dart**

```
import 'package:dartz/dartz.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:mockito/mockito.dart';
import 'package:ola_desktop/modules/login/domain/entities/login_user.dart';
import 'package:ola_desktop/modules/login/domain/repositories/login_repository.dart';
import 'package:ola_desktop/modules/login/domain/usecases/login_with_user.dart';

class LoginRepositoryMock extends Mock implements LoginRepository {}

main() {
  final repository = LoginRepositoryMock();
  final usecase = LoginWithUserImpl(repository);

  test('Deve retornar um LoginUser', () async {
    // ignore: prefer_const_constructors
    when(repository.login(user: '', password: ''))
        .thenAnswer((_) async => Right(LoginUser.empty()));

    final result = await usecase("gabriel.ribeiro", "123456");
    expect(result, isA<LoginUser>());
  });
}
```

**login_repository.dart**

```
import 'package:dartz/dartz.dart';

import '../entities/login_user.dart';
import '../errors/errors.dart';

abstract class LoginRepository {
  Future<Either<FailureLogin, LoginUser>> login(
      {required String user, required String password});
}
```

**login_with_user.dart**

```
import 'package:dartz/dartz.dart';

import '../entities/login_user.dart';
import '../errors/errors.dart';
import '../repositories/login_repository.dart';

abstract class LoginWithUser {
  Future<Either<FailureLogin, LoginUser>> call(String user, String password);
}

class LoginWithUserImpl implements LoginWithUser {
  final LoginRepository repository;

  LoginWithUserImpl(this.repository);

  @override
  Future<Either<FailureLogin, LoginUser>> call(String user, String password) {
    return repository.login(user: user, password: password);
  }
}
```

**login_user.dart**

```
class LoginUser {
  final String user;
  final String password;

  LoginUser({required this.user, required this.password});

  factory LoginUser.empty() {
    return LoginUser(user: '', password: '');
  }
}
```

**errors.dart**

```
abstract class FailureLogin implements Exception {}
```

[image: Print explorer folder Lib]

[image: Print explorer folder Test]

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Great afternoon!

Manage to solve, this extends Mock is thing before nullsafety
after nullsafety this no longer works. Had to use `GenerateMock`

**class test**

[image]

Then I ran the code in the terminal to generate class **mocks**:

```
flutter pub run build_runner build
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not totaly sure but maybe is releated with Either<FailureLogin, LoginUser>, can you rewrite the test codes with result.isRight(), if it is works re check the expect(result, isA()); line. because result can be Right or left but is Either type.

also can you check the `repository.login(user: '', password: '')` replacing with `await repository.login(user: '', password: '')`

Comment: When I run the test (login_with_user_test.dart) it is returning the error on the line `when(repository.login(user: '', password: '')).thenAnswer((_) async => Right(LoginUser.empty() ));`

And the message is that in the file (login_repository.dart): `type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Future<Either<FailureLogin, LoginUser>>'`

Comment: I'm learning dart/flutter and I went to make a simple login class using clean dart architecture for project organization and I'm apaiando: https://github.com/Flutterando/Clean-Dart

Comment: Brother, error is simple, one of the Future<Either<FailureLogin, LoginUser>> returner function, return the null so you must check the LoginWithUser usecases calls. So  repository.login(user: user, password: password); check this function and put some print in login because it is return null or something(You can check the your api result, maybe your backend team sending value like null on wrong user info.).